# Good practice to access WebDAV over SSL on a local network

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate, webdav

I have a relatively simple scenario, where a WebDAV server runs over HTTPS, in a local network. For a test run (and it could end up being the final solution as well) I'm running as server [sftpgo](https://github.com/drakkan/sftpgo/blob/main/docs/webdav.md) on a Windows 10 host.
Note that it all looks to run fine, but... the setup appears to me as more complex than it should be (and not because of the chosen server).

I had to create a dummy CA and certificate, and import it into the client device - still a Windows host, in this test case the same machine on 127.0.0.1.
Then I had to fiddle with `hosts` file to make sure the certificate, on a fictitious domain name like xanadu.local, is valid.

When I have to replicate it in a production environment everything can become annoyingly complex!
Note that this server will always be accessed on a local network, like on 192.168.0.100; the SSL transport layer would just avoid anyone peeking in transferred data and authorization access.

What could be a better/simpler solution, from the perspective of configuration?

[EDIT]
I've also to assume that the internet could be *unreachable* from the local network, so no external trusted CA could be inquired. Still, the WebDAV transfers should work flawlessly.

Comment: So get a proper certificate signed by a trusted authority.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Would make sense asking a certificate from a trusted CA on a domain that **can't** be registered? Being on a local network I would use something like "foo.local". Note also that the internet itself could be _unreachable_ from the local network, so I can even assume the trusted CA is unreachable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can distill two questions:

> What could be a simpler solution, from the perspective of configuration?

Don't use SSL.

I'm going to get criticized in the comments for this, but depending on your risk analysis, it might be perfectly ok. No one can make this assessment besides yourself (or your management). *(Note that the pros/cons and the assessment itself are highly specific and mostly opinion based, thus out of scope on SuperUser)*

Another simple solution is to use SSL, but disable any client-side validation. Then you avoid the certificate/CA distribution problem. No one could casually snoop on your data in transit, but they could perform a man-in-the-middle attack and get it that way. Again, risk analysis.

> What could be a better solution, from the perspective of configuration?

Two solutions come to mind:

- Get a certificate from an external certificate authority. You can still use a domain name in the "global address space" of DNS. I use `*.int.mtak.nl` for all my home stuff and I can create certificates with that perfectly fine, even though the domain names don't permanently exist on the internet. They have to, at some point, for validation by Let's Encrypt, but that can be avoided by using another CA with a different validation process. Note that the information in DNS at time of validation doesn't have to be correct; it just needs the domain name to exist.
  With regards to connectivity: Certificate validation is an offline process. The only reason you'd need internet access is to check OCSP/CRLs for revocations. Again, this is a risk you need to assess.
- Create your own certificate authority and import it on all the clients. This way you can have a completely offline CA, for which you control the validation, certificate issuance and CRL distribution. Distribution of the CA to clients can be done with automation tools (Ansible, Puppet, shell scripts, whatever). If you are in an Active Directory domain, the domain likely already provides a CA that lives on all Domain clients (which saves a lot of hassle).
  Be careful with this though. Setting up a CA is fairly simple. Doing it right, and getting a more secure system than an external CA is *very* hard.

Comment: Your ideas sound tickling, as my need for _security_ is (possibly) relatively loose - just to avoid a plain sniff of data, not important enough data to justify anyone setting up a MITM attack. I'm investigating disabling validation on my client. Not sure about the _dummy_ certificate, as I could need anyway a few server certificates